# What are the disadvantages of setting every property to strong?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

As a new iOS programmer, I've had a slew of bugs to fix today, a few of them have been related to me using weak properties instead of strong.

I realise that a good programmer wouldn't have this problem and would only set the properties to strong that need to be, but nonetheless, in my newbie eyes, I can't see why I should use weak, it only adds the risk of problems.

Comment: Voting to reopen. I don't think that closing this one as a duplicate was a good call: the central issue of this question is *usage* of strong vs. weak, while the central issue of the other question is the *behavior* of strong vs. weak.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight That doesn't change the fact that it's an unresearched poll. It shan't be closed as a duplicate, but as "too broad".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In general, you should decide between `weak`, `strong`, `assign`, and `copy` by looking at the relationship between the class holding the property and the value of that property, and also the kind of the property being passed.

- If the property being set is primitive, use `assign` (or do not use ownership qualifier at all)
- If the property being set is a scalar, immutable object, use `strong`
- If the property being set is a scalar, mutable object implementing `NSCopying` protocol, use `copy`
- If the property being set is mutable, and the ownership is transferred to your object, use `strong`
- If the property being set is a mutable object implementing `NSCopying` protocol, but the ownership remains with the caller, use `copy`
- If the property being set is a back reference (i.e. a "to parent" property in a "child" object), use `weak`.

The concept of ownership is very important in reference counted memory models. This is the primary driving factor behind your decision. You need to decide where is the primary owner of an object, and give that owner a strong reference. If an ownership is shared among a group of objects, give them all a strong reference.

The most difficult situation is when objects could own each other, directly or indirectly. In this case you would be better off replacing "ownership" with "knows about", give all objects a common "top" owner who "owns" everybody, and model the "knows about" relationships with `weak` references.

Comment: This is the best answer. One point of clarification, though. The term "scalar" to me means a simple non-object data type that holds a value, like int, float, char, etc. For these, you use assign, because you don't manage memory for them.

Comment: This is a poor answer for a new programmer. If they don't know if they should keep a strong or weak reference, they certainly won't know what a scalar immutable value is

Comment: Another point: There is another case you don't mention: Shared ownership. Sometimes in your design, multiple objects can both have an owning reference to the same object. Example, a graphing program that can create 2D and 3D graphs of the same function object. Both types of graph may need to own the formula object they graph. The formula object may be mutable, and if the user changes the formula, you want those changes to appear in any active graphs, so copy is not the correct choice.

Comment: @davbryn What in the world makes you **assume** this??? `strong` and `weak` are concepts that are specific to reference-counting environments. Mutable and scalar, on the other hand, are general CS concepts that are familiar to a much wider audience - say, most Java, VB, and C# programmers are familiar with these concepts.

Comment: @DuncanC Thanks for great comments! I tried to deal with shared ownership in the last paragraph of the answer. There's no universal recipe here, though, so I made one suggestion that could deal with the issue (but there's of course other ways to do it). Thanks!

Comment: @dasblinkenlight I **assume** this since the asker is obviously unfamiliar with reference-counting environment. Not all programmers will have studied CS (and I'd wager that you could assume the majority of .net developers, in practice, would not be familiar with memory management to a large degree (such is the nature of the environment their code executes in)). This is a beginner question, explicitly asking for some hand-holding

Comment: @davbryn It looks like [OP has previous exposure to Java](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:1639615+[java]) Since mutability concept is central to understanding Java strings, I think that it wouldn't be unreasonable to assume at least some familiarity with the subject.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight `copy` should be used for any object type that implements the `NSCopying` protocol, generally.  This includes `NSString`, `NSArray`, `NSDictionary`, etc... copying an immutable object is free.  Copying a mutable object is not, but copying is the correct behavior.

Comment: @bbum Thanks for a great comment! I edited the answer to reflect this.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Are there any scalar immutable types that don't implement NSCopying? Your second rule needs to go, and I think it'd be wise to simplify things by just omitting discussion of "scalar" anything -- it doesn't affect the choice between strong and weak.

Comment: @Caleb That's an interesting suggestion - I am reluctant to remove that point, because one could build his own immutable scalar (say, something along the lines of `BigDecimal` in Java). I may start using `copy` for built-in copyable types in my own code, though :-) Thanks!

Comment: @bbum why is copying an immutable object free? (computation wise I assume)

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Why should primitives use `assign`? The qualifiers apply only to object types. `assign` works with a primitive because it does nothing, that doesn't mean you should use it, right?

Comment: @ValentinRadu Copying immutable objects is "free" because immutable objects are retained instead of copied (they can't be changed, so there's never a reason to need two with the same value). The qualifiers apply to all properties, but `strong`, `weak`, and `copy` don't make sense for non-objects; the only one that makes sense is `assign`.

Comment: @Caleb That's the point,`assign` doesn't make sense either at conceptual level.It's there just because it sort of perpetuated through time. Probably when people learn the language, they feel the need to have some kind of qualifier there for primitives as well. It's simply a bad habit. We should not spread it. It makes no sense for primitive values, and it doesn't apply to non retainable objects, in the same manner the others don't. Here are the docs: http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html and http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#ownership-qualification

Comment: @Caleb And yes, I did all that research on `assign` because I'm lazy  when it comes to code typing and I would like to spread my laziness on others here :)

Answer (score 1):

`weak` and `strong` are very important to get right for memory management purposes.

`strong` will increase the reference counter for the pointer, and you effectively say that you own the object.

`weak` does not increase the reference counter, and the object can potentially disappear at any time. If you have a cyclic dependency, you should use `weak` to avoid a memory leak (two objects both having a strong reference to each other is a cyclic dependency and those objects will never be released).

You should always think about your memory management, but a good rule of thumb is that the property should always be `strong`, unless you positively know that it is retained elsewhere. Multiple objects can have a `strong` reference to the same object with no problems, as long as no cyclic references occur.

Answer (score 1):

Some super basic rules of thumb:

If you want the object to stick around *at least* until you are finished with it, go with **strong**

If you can handle the object disappearing without it hurting you too bad (i.e it is the parent that created you that might be *nice* to know about but not super important) then use **weak**

if it is not an **NSObject** (so is an int, bool float or other primitive type) use **assign**.

Answer (score -3):

A rule of thumb that I use is: if the object is retained somewhere else, use weak. The biggest thing for me is when using interface builder. If you have an `IBOutlet`, you can make it weak, because that object is taken care of in interface builder and in the XIB file

Comment: Your rule of thumb is a very bad idea. Something should keep a strong reference if it needs to keep a hold on the object. That decision is generally made without any consideration to whether anything else has a strong reference or not.

Comment: -1 Don't rely on other objects to do your memory management for you.

Comment: this is actually mostly true for OS X but it absolutely isn't for iOS where the membership is turned around a little bit.